# jQuery getting children of children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a problem and I can't understand what is happening.
I'm dealing with this problem for a few hours.

I'm trying to get the text from some `DIV`s  after the `li` is clicked.

Here is the html of the `ul` list and the `li`:

```
<ul id="thumbsUL" runat="server" class="thumbs noscript">
    <li>
        <a class="thumb" name="leaf" href="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3261/2538183196_8baf9a8015.jpg" title="Title #0">
           <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3261/2538183196_8baf9a8015_s.jpg" alt="Title #0" />
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="image-title">Title #0</div>
            <div class="image-desc">Description</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

here is the script (one of the most i've tried):

```
$("#thumbsUL li").click(function () {
    var title = $(this).children(".caption").children(".image-title").text();
    alert(title);
});
```

the alert fire but without the text of the image title text.

1.what am i doing worng?

2.is there a better way then this to get the children?

3.is `$(".selector").text()` is the best way to get the content of the element text?

Comment: It's working fine, although the selector could be simpler without the calls of `children()` -- Are you missing the end tag? `</ul>`? -- http://jsfiddle.net/26pZY/

Comment: thats wierd, i need to recheck my html line by line but with first look nothing is worng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
$("#thumbsUL li").click(function () {
    var title = $(this).find(".image-title").html();
    alert(title);    
});
```

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal for some reson it return null any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Your selector returns a collection of elements. Use a more specific selector and you´ll be fine. In my example I´m using [first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/).

`var title = $(this).find('.image-title').first().text();`

Comment: it return empty string for me i dont why .

Comment: I´d missed the class prefix `.`. You should also wrap your code that binds the `click` event in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`

Comment: thx for the help! but i got this working, i found out it was some other part of my code, who didnt let me get the info i want.